# Pasting images from outlook without linking

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word-2010

I often paste images from emails to a word document by using Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V (copy and paste). The problem is that this seems to create a linked image; and whenever I update links in the document (Ctrl-A + F9), this breaks all of these images.

I found out that I can choose the "Image" option when I paste the image and it doesn't break it when I update afterwards. The problem is I can't seem to find a way to make this option the default option.

I go in File->Options->Advanced Options-> Copy and paste but there is no default paste for images, only for text. Am I missing something?

My version of office is Office 2010.

Thanks in advance to everyone who answers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a perfect solution for this, however here is something to make it easier for you.

Turn on the Paste Options button

The Paste Options button is turned on by default. If you don't see the button, it might be turned off. Follow these steps to turn it on.

In Word 2010, 2013, or 2016, click File > Options > Advanced.

In the Cut, copy, and paste section, select the Show Paste Options button when content is pasted check box.

Click OK.

Now when you paste it shows an additional icon with the pasted content to let you easily modify to the picture as you stated.

A workaround would be to save the images to your drive and drag that file into the document.  This is unfortunately more difficult but would solve the link issue without having to select that the content is an image ect.